# Add conditions to a v-for in Vue

Tags: vuejs3

Is there possible to add conditions on looping out arrays in Vue? Like with the example down below, I loop an array of persons into a table:

```html
    <CTableRow v-for="person in persons" :key="person.status">
      <CTableDataCell>{{ person.id }}</CTableDataCell>
      <CTableDataCell>{{ person.name }}</CTableDataCell>
      <CTableDataCell>{{ person.age }}</CTableDataCell>
    </CTableRow>
```

If I have an element in persons named "active" (i.e `person.active`) can I somehow only loop through persons who are active and further down the Vue file loop through the persons who are not active, **using the same data source**?

If I can use some pseudocode, I want to achieve something like this:

```html
    <CTableRow v-for="person in persons" :key="person.status">
      if( person.active === true) {
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.id }}</CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.name }}</CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.age }}</CTableDataCell>
      }
    </CTableRow>
    
    <CTableRow v-for="person in persons" :key="person.status">
      if( person.active === false) {
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.id }}</CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.name }}</CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.age }}</CTableDataCell>
      }
    </CTableRow>
```

Is this possible in Vue, and what would be the best practice?

Update:
I realized I could add a v-if on all the TableDataCells as a solution to my problem. Or is it better to create two arrays in the composition api?

Comment: Best practice is to filter the array you pass to template. You can do it using at least two ways. `computed()` property or by temporary array where you filter records you need from original array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
<CTableRow v-for="person in persons" :key="person.status">
    <template v-if="person.active">
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.id }}</CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.name }}</CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>{{ person.age }}</CTableDataCell>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <CTableDataCell>Something Else</CTableDataCell>
    </template>
</CTableRow>
```

The `<template>` is just a container which won't get rendered.

Comment: And this is a bad practice. How he should do it when he needs items `.active` and `.age >= 18` ?

Comment: @Mises Why would it be?

Comment: And he needs all filtering possibilities. Like sometimes all user age and sometimes only if they are `>= 18`. Just don't filter it in template.

Comment: First, that wasn't a question . Second, you could still do that with a method returning boolean for your condition.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I should filter out the array in the composition api and use a different array in each segment if I later want to compute any data?

Comment: That's a better solution I think, yes. But It depends on what your goal is and if you need to work with the filtered data somehow more.

Comment: @digitalniweb You are just hiding result using `v-if` in a template. Template will have a bunch of empty rows with `<--! v-if -->` in it.

Comment: @mises And that's why it is a "bad practice"? As I said, It depends on what you need. I don't really think there is a problem when you have few "useless" comments in code in general. I was responding to his question, don't know what his level of skill is and his requirements are. What I suggested was sufficient enough. And for sure not wrong at all.

Comment: @DavidLar Use computed properties to make a static/unchangeable filter for ref array. Your template won't render odd empty rows with `<!-- v-if -->` in it. And populate the array and filter it using some conditions if you need more powerful many filters.

Comment: @digitalniweb Yeah not wrong but buggy definitely. Now try to highlight every second row. So it looks nice. Good luck with it.

Comment: @Mises Did I miss the part where he asked to highlight every second row?

Comment: @digitalniweb You miss all good job opportunities if you program like that.